# powershell windows form browes dialogue

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

Im trying to create a windows form that has a button when clicked will display a folder/file browes window, then the user selects the file/folder and clicks OK and i can then use the selected path as a string for another script.

the problem is that when i run it through PowerGUI (powershell scripting app) it works fine, but when i run through windows powershell  it hangs when loading the browse dialog, anyone seen this before or see what ive done wrong or got an alternative, any help would be appreciated.

```
cls
$button = $browse = $form = 0
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$browse = new-object system.windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$browse.RootFolder = [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]'MyComputer'
$browse.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
$browse.selectedPath = "C:\"
$browse.Description = "Choose a directory"

$button1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Text = "Choose Directory"
$button1.Add_Click({$browse.ShowDialog()})
$button1.left = 20
$button1.top = 20

$form = New-Object system.windows.forms.Form
$form.controls.add($button1)
$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()

$browse.SelectedPath
```

Comment: I'm on windows7 x32, powershell v3.0 and your code works in console and in ISE.

Comment: Script works fine on my Windows 7 x64 and PowerShell 2.0 console. Is it possible that PowerGui has installed something that may be keeping your script from executing? Also try adding { $ErrorActionPreference = Inquire } to find out if any errors are passing you by? Or use some { write-hosts "xxxxx" } to get a better idea of where your app is hanging and then update your question.

Comment: yep my powershell comand screen keeps running as version 1 but when i do $psversiontable in PS i can see, i have V2 installed but my script does not run as V2 strange :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works when I try it. However I have noticed that sometimes(especially the 2nd time in a session) I use a browsewindow, it is hidden behind the PowerShell console and it seems like it's stuck. So can you try moving your powershell console to the side when it "hangs"?

Also, as a suggestion: if you're only using the form to select a folder location, I would skip it. You won't recieve the browser value until you close the form anyways, so try something like this instead:

```
function Get-BrowseLocation
{
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $browse.RootFolder = [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]'MyComputer'
    $browse.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
    $browse.Description = "Choose a directory"

    $loop = $true
    while($loop)
    {
        if ($browse.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
        {
            $loop = $false
        } else
        {
            $res = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You clicked Cancel. Try again or exit script?", "Choose a directory", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel)
            if($res -eq "Cancel")
            {
                #End script
                return
            }
        }
    }
    $browse.SelectedPath
    $browse.Dispose()
}

PS > Get-BrowseLocation
D:\
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem when running my script through PowerShellPlus (anther powershell editor). Luckily I found [this post](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2314443) that shows how to prompt for a folder without using the FolderBrowserDialog.  Here's the code that I'm using in [a set of powershell functions I've written](http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-multi-line-input-box-dialog-open-file-dialog-folder-browser-dialog-input-box-and-message-box/) for prompting the user for many different kinds of input via a GUI.

```
# Show an Open Folder Dialog and return the directory selected by the user.
function Read-FolderBrowserDialog([string]$Message, [string]$InitialDirectory)
{
    $app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, $Message, 0, $InitialDirectory)
    if ($folder) { return $folder.Self.Path } else { return '' }
}
```

Comment: Nice shell based solution, instead of using .NET Windows Forms!

Answer (score 1):

If you make the following changes to the function provided by Frode. F, the dialog will always come to the top.

```
$topform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$topform.Topmost = $true
$topform.MinimizeBox = $true

$loop = $true
while($loop)
{
    if ($browse.ShowDialog($topform) -eq "OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're experiencing the issue I've faced, which is addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216710/call-openfiledialog-from-powershell/216769#216769)

The answer suggests setting `.ShowHelp` to `$true`, like this:

```
$openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.openFileDialog
$openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
$openFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: This trick only works for the OpenFileDialog; the FolderBrowserDialog does not have a ShowHelp property that can be set to true.