# call FolderBrowserDialog from powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216710/call-openfiledialog-from-powershell), after running the following code the browser dialog does appear with all the correct buttons, but the selection area that usally displays available folders is missing:

```
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' )
$d = New-Object Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$d.ShowDialog( )
```

Comment: If anyone's interested, this is what I was using it for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182573/powershell-cli-or-gui-which-do-you-need-or-prefer#216936

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I encountered this problem a while back and found the following COM workaround on the MSDN forums:

```
$app = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $app.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, "C:\")
if ($folder.Self.Path -ne "") {write-host "You selected " $folder.Self.Path}
```

http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms.controls&tid=3607557a-43b3-40bf-8276-be00526e0520&p=1

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is a problem with PowerShell running in a MTA Thread.  You can run the CTP of  Version 2 in a STA (single threaded apartment) mode and it will pull up the proper folder selection.  It does pull the menu up behind the shell window though.

Comment: I tried this first on Vista with CTP2, where I could get it working with in STA mode.  On XP with V1, I was not able to get this working.

Comment: The STA limitation makes sense . . . eagerly awaiting the release version of PS v2 ;)

Comment: It might be a while :( .  CTP3 is coming soon (possibly for release at PDC, but there has not been a formal announcement that I'm aware of.  Unfortunately, with the CTP series, things can be added, removed, or changed, by the time it gets to release.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, if you are looking to do Windows Forms stuff, there is one product currently out that will do windows forms for PowerShell (The [Admin Script Editor](http://www.adminscripteditor.com/)) and Sapien is working on a [Forms Designer](http://hosted.verticalresponse.com/172892/13e80641d0/176000434/c46cbf224d/) (announced on the [PowerScripting Podcast](http://powerscripting.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/episode-45-rockin-roundtable/)), which might smooth out some of these issues for your script.